# is expression "spend money stupidly" common in everyday conversation?

Tags: word-usage

Ex: he spends his money stupidly (ie waste lots of money for non-sense things)

If the above expression is not common then what is the alternative?

Comment: It's not a fixed phrase for expressing the idea, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: I agree with Stoney. It isn't common or uncommon, but it is something one could correctly say in the situation you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "spend money stupidly" is not a common phrase.  This is probably because "stupid" is rude enough to offend, but polite enough not to be used when someone *intends* to offend.  It sounds kind of childish.

One common phrase would be to "waste money".  For instance:  He got rich playing the Lottery, but he quickly wasted all the money on fast cars and gambling.

Comment: It's common enough that a google search yielded 5960 instances of "spends money stupidly" - https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22spends+money+stupidly%22

Comment: No, not 5960 instances (Google counts are notoriously inaccurate, especially for low-count phrases).  Try clicking forward to one of the later pages - there's less than 100 real hits.